# Node Permissions Issue, running package commands from prompt

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know this is a common issue with Node installations where the node isn't added to the environment paths.  I've verified this.  Place of employment has it locked up somehow and I am trying to figure out what exactly would be blocking it.

I've installed node successfully, cmd line has admin rights but limited.  So I can't run node/npm from command line.  So, I side stepped moved onto Git Bash and PowerShell successfully.  To keep it limited to Git Bash, I've had to manually add npm packages bower, pm2, mocha, etc. to the env. paths manually from the ../User/../Roaming directory.  So in bash I can run things like npm -v, node -v, mocha version etc.  I can even install, npm install -g mocha.

Where it gets tricky is when I do npm test (with mocha configured in the package.json) mocha initiates but fails and tells me node isn't recognized as internal or external...

Any ideas?

Here are my configuration files:

`{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Mocha Tests",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
      "args": [
        "-u",
        "tdd",
        "--timeout",
        "999999",
        "--colors",
        "${workspaceRoot}/test"
      ],
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
    },
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\test.js"
    }
  ]
}`

`{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test project to walkthrough Mocha",
  "main": "test.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha test"
  },
  "author": "some guy",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
     "mocha": "^3.4.2"
  }
}`

Comment: I am looking mostly to find what could be possible blockers.  So I can properly form my request to higher to get this block removed.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out.  I am running from VS Code and I didn't have the proper configuration in place.  I was trying to just run from the command line, which I think I should be able to but haven't successfully.  With the proper configuration in place I can debug the tests successfully.